# Undecidability and the representation theory of $K<X,Y>$

Tags: representation-theory, computability

The question comes from the problem here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73940/are-wild-problems-related-to-undecidable-ones It has already been proven that the representation theory of $K<X,Y>$ is undecidable. May I ask what does that mean? Does it mean that it is inherently impossible for the indecomposable representations of $K<X,Y>$ to ever be classified? Or the classification, albeit hard, is still theoretically possible?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5895/what-are-tame-and-wild-hereditary-algebras

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I have read a lot of questions including this one (and even asked one) on MO on the wild problem, yet none of these actually provides a good answer I need. I know we can not write all indecomposable representations of a wild quiver (or hereditary algebra) using finitely many parameters but what about infinitely many of them? My main question is: is the problem of wild representation type ever solvable (probably with some new theory, with countably many or even uncountably many parameters) in the future? Or is this problem at least theoretically partly unsolvable?